# Reactjs(v.15) make sibling component as children

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I have a component hierarchy like below(Source), My requirement is, while rendering would like to convert this into `Target` upon some property, here I am assuming as `flag`

**Source:**

```
<Parent>
   <Xyz flag={false}/>
   <One flag={true}/>
   <Two flag={true}/>
   <Three flag={true}/>
</Parent>
```

**Target:**

```
<Parent>
   <Xyz>
      <One />
      <Two />
      <Three />
   </Xyz>
</Parent>
```

My approach:

In side render of **Parent**

```
render() {
    const xyz = this.props.children.filter((children) => !children.props.flag);

    const kids = this.props.children.filter((children) => children.props.flag);

    const clonedXyz = React.cloneElement(xyz, [{...props}], [...kids]);
    return(
        <div>
            {clonedXyz}
        </div>
        );
}
```

Which is throwing error expected class/function but got `undefined` in react v15.x

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) it might help us and you more if you took a step back and explain how you reached this (rather odd) requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer, https://codesandbox.io/s/7ww8n4my9x

it should be `React.cloneElement(xyz[0], [{...props}], kids)`